# Visual bug when converting an html page to a PDF

Tags: css, pdf

I have a visual bug when rendering my website in PDF. As you can see on the screen shot there is a shift in the images. But on the html rendering this shift is not present.

the link of the website to be transformed: https://betterhost-3fadc.web.app/

```
<article>
<div class="container"><img
        src="https://www.electrodepot.fr/fstrz/r/s/www.electrodepot.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/1a40d1f945549a9ec18309b0a600e55c/P939881.jpg?frz-v=2690"><img
        src="https://www.electrodepot.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/1a40d1f945549a9ec18309b0a600e55c/P959338.jpg"><img
        src="https://www.alinea.com/fstrz/r/s/www.alinea.com/dw/image/v2/BCKM_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-ali_master/default/dwb3523209/images/27339299/POUBELLE-DAYA-27339299-F-1.jpg?sw=982&amp;sh=982&amp;sm=fit&amp;sfrm=png&amp;bgcolor=eef1eb&amp;frz-v=103"><img
        src="https://cdn.sklum.com/fr/1172047/distributeur-de-savon-en-verre-ovie.jpg"><img
        src="https://www.alinea.com/fstrz/r/s/www.alinea.com/dw/image/v2/BCKM_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-ali_master/default/dw32eea630/images/27258507/BROSSE-WC-SPINA-27258507-F-1.jpg?sw=982&amp;sh=982&amp;sm=fit&amp;sfrm=png&amp;bgcolor=eef1eb&amp;frz-v=103"><img
        src="https://www.electrodepot.fr/fstrz/r/s/www.electrodepot.fr/media/catalog/product/cache/1a40d1f945549a9ec18309b0a600e55c/P963865.jpg?frz-v=2690"><img
        src="https://cdn.sklum.com/fr/1172188/gobelet-en-verre-ovie.jpg"></div>
<cactus>
```

Each page is in a block called article.

```css
article {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 827px;
    height: 1170px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The images are arranged in 2 columns via this CSS code:

```css
.container {columns: 2;width: 50%;column-gap: 0px;height: auto;}
```

Web:

[image: Code render web]

PDF:

[image: PDF RENDER]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. We don't know what HTML is being used, so we can't intelligently guess as to how your CSS is being applied. Nor can we tell from pictures of code, so please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide at least the web part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dedicated print style sheet to make reliable PDFs. use a media query to make a style sheet for print. In your markup have everything for one sheet of a4 in a container called something like .page. Then in your print style sheet, explore using @page to format the pdf.

in print.css

```
.page {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

That should stop your layout within your class="page" container from breaking across two pages. Experiment with using real dimensions in your print style sheet to make everything fit on one page as you want. You can see what your pdf is going to look like by doing ctrl+p to see the print preview, or actually saving to pdf from chrome.

That should start you in the right direction.

EDIT: some other pointers

put this to take the default margins off when printing

```
@page 
{
    size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
    margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
```

Set your page container to nearly the size of the page you want to print

```
.page {
width:209mm;height:296mm;background-color:#fffffe;position:relative;border:1px solid transparent
}
```